# Server TLS handshake failed

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, kubernetes-pod, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Whenever my application tries to run `gateway.connect(connectionProfile, connectionOptions);` I get the following errors:

```
error: [ServiceEndpoint]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: peer0org1, url:grpcs://0.0.0.0:30012, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
error: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server peer0org1 url:grpcs://0.0.0.0:30012 timeout:3000
info: [NetworkConfig]: buildPeer - Unable to connect to the endorser peer0org1 due to Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: peer0org1, url:grpcs://0.0.0.0:30012, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
error: [ServiceEndpoint]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: peer0org2, url:grpcs://0.0.0.0:30015, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
error: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server peer0org2 url:grpcs://0.0.0.0:30015 timeout:3000
info: [NetworkConfig]: buildPeer - Unable to connect to the endorser peer0org2 due to Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: peer0org2, url:grpcs://0.0.0.0:30015, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
```

and in the peer logs I see these error messages:

```
[core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 06f Server TLS handshake failed in 2.895908ms with error tls: failed to verify client certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority server=ChaincodeServer remoteaddress=192.168.15.6:52552
[core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 070 Server TLS handshake failed in 4.805823ms with error tls: failed to verify client certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority server=ChaincodeServer remoteaddress=192.168.15.6:52560
[core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 071 Server TLS handshake failed in 2.988008ms with error tls: failed to verify client certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority server=ChaincodeServer remoteaddress=192.168.15.6:52576
[core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 072 Server TLS handshake failed in 2.223583ms with error tls: failed to verify client certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority server=ChaincodeServer remoteaddress=192.168.15.6:52598
```

I'm running my network on a local microk8s kubernetes cluster. All peers and orderers pods have their own `NodePort` type of `Service`. I'm also running my chaincode as an external service on pods, one for each organization.

All certificates were generated with Fabric-CAs: 1 for TLS certificates for communication and 1 RCA for each organization.

I'm not running my application on a pod, I just run `node app.js`

Here is my application code:

```
async function funcName(...) {

    const wallet = await Wallets.newFileSystemWallet('path/to/wallet');

    const gateway = new Gateway();

    try {

        const userName = 'User1@org1.example.com';

        let connectionProfile = yaml.load(fs.readFileSync('./gateway/networkConnection.yaml', 'utf8'));

        let connectionOptions = {
            identity: userName,
            wallet: wallet,
            discovery: { enabled:true, asLocalhost: true }
        };

        await gateway.connect(connectionProfile, connectionOptions);
    ...
```

And here is my networkConnection.yaml:

```
---
name: "test-network"

x-type: "hlfv1"

description: "Description"

version: "1.0"

client:
  organization: Org1

channels:
  canalhash:
    orderers:
      - orderer1
      - orderer2
      - orderer3
      - orderer4
      - orderer5

    peers:
      peer0org1:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true

organizations:
  Org1:
    mspid: Org1MSP

    peers:
      - peer0org1

    certificateAuthorities:
      - rca-org1

  Org2:
    mspid: Org2MSP

    peers:
      - peer0org2

orderers:
  orderer1:
    url: grpcs://0.0.0.0:30017

    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: orderer1

    tlsCACerts:
      path: /home/network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tls-ca-cert.pem

  orderer2:
    url: grpcs://0.0.0.0:30018

    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: orderer2

    tlsCACerts:
      path: /home/network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tls-ca-cert.pem

  orderer3:
    url: grpcs://0.0.0.0:30019

    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: orderer3

    tlsCACerts:
      path: /home/network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tls-ca-cert.pem

  orderer4:
    url: grpcs://0.0.0.0:30020

    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: orderer4

    tlsCACerts:
      path: /home/network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tls-ca-cert.pem

  orderer5:
    url: grpcs://0.0.0.0:30021

    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: orderer5

    tlsCACerts:
      path: /home/network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tls-ca-cert.pem

peers:
  peer0org1:
    url: grpcs://0.0.0.0:30012

    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0org1
      request-timeout: 120001

    tlsCACerts:
      path: /home/network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls-ca/tls-ca-cert.pem

  peer0org2:
    url: grpcs://0.0.0.0:30015
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0org2
      request-timeout: 120001

    tlsCACerts:
      path: /home/network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls-ca/tls-ca-cert.pem

certificateAuthorities:
  rca-org1:
    url: https://0.0.0.0:30009
    httpOptions:
      verify: false
    tlsCACerts: 
      path: /home/storage/rca-org1/crypto/ca-cert.pem

    registrar:
      - enrollId: admin
        enrollSecret: adminpw
    caName: rca-org1

  rca-org2:
    url: https://0.0.0.0:30010
    httpOptions:
      verify: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: /home/storage/rca-org1/crypto/ca-cert.pem
    registrar:
      - enrollId: admin
        enrollSecret: adminpw
    caName: rca-org2

  tls-ca:
    url: https://0.0.0.0:30007
    httpOptions:
      verify: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: /home/storage/tls-ca/crypto/ca-cert.pem
    registrar:
      - enrollId: tls-ca-admin
        enrollSecret: tls-ca-adminpw
    caName: tls-ca
```

Does somebody knows what's causing these errors? If more information about my network is needed just ask for it and I'll edit my question with it.

Comment: It's likely that the `root_cert` field in your *connection.json* file for your chaincode does not contain the root cert which signed the TLS certificate for the peer.

Comment: I thought of this too but even though I modified the connection.json I'm still getting those errors but I think there is one thing that needs to be done. @GariSingh do you know how can I reference the certificate I generated for my application? I generated it with `fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://app:appPW@0.0.0.0:30007 --enrollment.profile tls` and registered it with `fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name app --id.secret appPW --id.type client -u https://0.0.0.0:30007`. Do you know if that's necessary and if I did it correctly?